# Achieving Super or Subscript graticule labels in QGIS Composer windows?

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules, expression

It is quite common for paper topographic maps to label the map graticule with ordinate values in a mixture of superscript and standard digits, eg. ⁴123⁰⁰⁰ to emphasise the significant digits.

The QGIS Map composer allows graticules (termed grids) to be drawn on the map, and the ordinate labels to be customised, but does not recognise HTML tags such as `<sup>`.

Is there any other way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unicode has some superscript and subscript characters in it  as described [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

Here are two custom functions that can be entered in the QGIS [Python Function Editor](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/custom_python_functions.html) that superscript or subscript the digits in strings passed to them:

**Superscript**

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def supscr_num(inputText, feature, parent):
  """ Converts any digits in the input text into their Unicode superscript equivalent.
Expects a single string argument, returns a string"""
  supScr = (u'\u2070',u'\u00B9',u'\u00B2',u'\u00B3',u'\u2074',u'\u2075',u'\u2076',u'\u2077',u'\u2078',u'\u2079')
  outputText = ''

  for char in inputText:
    charPos = ord(char) - 48
    if charPos <0 or charPos > 9:
        outputText += char
    else:
        outputText += supScr[charPos]
  return outputText
```

**Subscript (updated to Python 3: unichr -> chr)**

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def subscr_num(inputText, feature, parent):
""" Converts any digits in the input text into their Unicode subscript equivalent.
Expects a single string argument, returns a string"""
  outputText = ''

  for char in inputText:
    charPos = ord(char) - 48
    if charPos <0 or charPos > 9:
        outputText += char
    else:
        outputText += chr(charPos + 8320)
  return outputText
```

These can then be used in an expression as follows:

```
supscr_num('4') || "123" || supscr_num('000')
```

Returning the ⁴123⁰⁰⁰ in the question

A more generic example of the same expression:

```
supscr_num(to_string(@grid_number // 100000)) || lpad ( to_string ( (@grid_number % 100000) // 1000),3,'0') || supscr_num(lpad (to_string(@grid_number % 1000),3,'0'))
```

Unfortunately there is incomplete support for the latin alphabet super and subscripts in unicode, so this technique cannot be extended completely.

**EDIT - Note on fonts**

Note that the unicode characters generated by the tool aren't present in every font. For example, using the following label expression:

```
 '1234567890'  || '\n'  ||  subscr_num(  '1234567890') ||  '\n'  || supscr_num(  '1234567890')
```

Generates the following using Arial:

[image: Arial exmaple]

But using Times New Roman all the digits are present:

[image: Times New Roman example]

Comment: This looks really promising - but how does one get the X or Y coords within an expression in the 'custom' option of the 'Draw coordinates' section?

Comment: There are two custom variables that are available (at the top of the list) in the expression editor - grid_axis (gives you the x or y axis), and grid_number (the ordinate)

Comment: Oops, incredibly obvious when you look. Excellent use of custom functions!

Comment: I've added a generic example using the @grid_number variable to illustrate

Comment: I am trying it and I do not get the subscript, and some of the superscript. I am using QGIS 2.18.14.

Comment: @Marco I've added an update to explain why this might happen.

Comment: @AndyHarfoot thanks, just test it with Times New Roman, but it does not work either. I will leave it for now. It would be nice to have LaTeX available  in in some way

Comment: @Marco Curious, what OS are you using? All my examples are in Windows

Comment: @AndyHarfoot Windows 7 Enterprise. I tried *Arial Unicode MS* and it worked for all numbers, also it did it for *Lucida Sans Unicode*, but not for letters, they do not became any script. Here the test `  'A'  || supscr_num('24A16') || 'B' ||  subscr_num('A2C6') ||  'X' || supscr_num(to_string("level") )`

Comment: @Marco The scripts only work on numbers (as noted in the answer there isn't a complete sub or superscript alphabet in unicode). Letters passed to the functions are returned unchanged. Interesting that you are seeing different behaviour to me with the same font. Maybe not every _Times New Roman_ is equal

Comment: Getting an error for the subscript unichr not defined is there a fix for that?

Comment: you just use char instead of unichar check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352018/cant-use-unichr-in-python-3-1

Comment: I've updated the code to replace unichr with chr so that it works with QGIS versions using Python 3

Answer (score 6):

If you have grid coordinates and want the first two figures to be large and the rest to be superscripts you can do it without python functions.

The trick is to use string processing to split the number into parts, and then replace the numbers with superscript numbers with the `replace` function.

```
concat(left(@grid_number,2),
       replace( substr(@grid_number,3,99) ,
                array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'),
                array('¹','²','³','⁴','⁵','⁶','⁷','⁸','⁹','⁰')
              )
       )
```

Put that as a custom format grid label with the expression button. Similar techniques can be used to have other parts of the label as superscripts or even subscripts.

Anything more complex than this I would do as a Python function.