# Using subscript in a QGIS Label Tool

Tags: qgis, labeling

In a Label Tool is it possible to display value of a point, for example 3.2 (double type), with subscript after a dot, like that: 3<sub>2</sub> ?

Comment: If you want this in the layout (composer) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181287/how-to-achieve-super-or-subscript-graticule-labels-in-qgis-composer-windows

Comment: You can try with this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192842/subscript-labels-in-qgis-legends/192850#192850

Answer (score 1):

You can use the custom functions shown in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181287/achieving-super-or-subscript-graticule-labels-in-qgis-composer-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) to write an expression that will achieve this when labelling.

Try this:

```
to_int( <VALUE> ) || subscr_num(  to_string( to_int(abs(<VALUE>  - to_int(<VALUE> ) )) * 10))
```

This will display the first decimal place as a subscript. Note that not all fonts have the unicode subscript characters, Lucida Sans is one that does work.