# subscript and superscript labeling in QGIS (v.2.18.2)

Tags: qgis, labeling

Could anybody help me to find out the solution:
how is possible to create labels with subscript and superscript, based on the attribute table (polygon shape)?
The example that I need to create is

[image]

This type of labeling is common in any kind of geological maps.
I'm using QGIS v.2.18.2

I will be extremaly glad to get answer, I hope it's possible.

Comment: If you want to show labels in legend of mapcomposer try this
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192842/subscript-labels-in-qgis-legends/192850#192850

Comment: The nicest way is still pending as I read here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/2856. We will see it in QGIS 3 I guess

Comment: I have tried this answer and works for single digits https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181287/achieving-super-or-subscript-graticule-labels-in-qgis-composer-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Superscript and subscript characters can be added manually using the copy and paste approach described in @ahmadhanb 's answer, but [this question and answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181287/achieving-super-or-subscript-graticule-labels-in-qgis-composer-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) details a pair of python functions that will allow such characters to be generated as part of an expression. The functions will operate on one to many digits in a string passed to them.

Example (QGIS expression):

```
subscr_num( 'P1')  || supscr_num( 'ub2') || subscr_num( '1')
```

Output:

[image: demo]

The simultaneous sub and superscript shown at the end of the example in the question can't be generated using this approach, they would have to be offset as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

According to the attached screenshot, you can see labels and label codes in the attribute table.

Below is a link to help you through the codes.
https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to add the subscript and superscript in the legend, then you can refer to this answer: [Subscript labels in QGIS legends](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192929/63384) which add details on how to do that. However, If you want to do that in the attribute table as you stated in your question, I am afraid you can only add superscript in the attribute table, but I couldn't find a way to do the same for subscript using the same method in the answer above. The strange thing that it is only allowed to add superscript up to number 3 (from 1 to 3) but if you have values above 3 it will be converted to normal size, although it is shown in the attribute table as superscript:

[image]

My guess is that the System font does not have superscript above the value 3 and the subscript does not exist at all.

[image]