# Insert meter square in layout map

Tags: layouts

Is it possible to insert an exponent for m^2 in QGIS for the layout?

[image]

Comment: AltGr + 2 does the trick.

Comment: Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/264372/29431 and this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/192842/29431